# Passing a function into another function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I want to pass a function into another function, but I have confused myself so much over the syntax and what is actually happening. This is the code I am running:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a){
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

void another_func(int p_func(int)){
int (*funcptr)(int) = p_func;
funcptr(7);
}

int main(void){

    another_func(func);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I have found out that I can put how many asterix I want before func when calling it in main, for example:

```
another_func(*******************func);
```

I can do the same when assigning the function to the function pointer, for example:

```
int (*funcptr)(int) = ***********p_func;
```

I am though forbidden to put an ampersand in front of p_func when assigning it to the function pointer. Also it doesn't seem to matter if I write:

```
void another_func(int (*p_func)(int)){
```

Can my plead for help wake some of the legendary C gods from their slumber who can make a detailed explanation? I really don't get how this works, what is passed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
>   operator, **a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’**’

On the other hand (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. **If the operand points to
>   a function, the result is a function designator**;

Thus you can place as many asterisks before a function designator as the compiler will allow according to its own limits.:)

And you may use operator `&` with a function designator. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f( int x )
{
    return x;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int ( *fp )( int ) = &f;

    printf( "%d\n", fp( 10 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that a function parameter declared as a function is adjusted to pointer to the function type.

Thus these two function declarations declare the same one function and can be both present in a compilation unit (though the function shall be defined once if it is not inline)

```
void another_func(int p_func(int));
void another_func(int ( *p_func )(int));
```

Comment: So in essence function expressions are always converted to function designators, no matter what?

Comment: @NoobDoob A function designator is always converted to function pointer with the rare exceptions listed in the presented quote from the C Standard.

Comment: So when I pass the function to another_func it automaticly becomes a pointer thus placing the ampersand before as I said illegal?

Comment: @DonkeyKing Yes, the argument is implicitly converted to a function pointer.

Comment: @DonkeyKing In this regard functions and arrays behave similarly.

Comment: But when I put the asterix before the assignation you said it would become a function designator, what exactly is that?

Comment: @DonkeyKing Yes but at once it is converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

*"I have found out that I can put how many asterix I want before func when calling it in main."* I don't want to offend you, but I suggest you to read something about pointers. An example about what you're looking for could be:

```
int foo(int (*foo2)(void))
{
    foo2();
}

int foo2(void)
{
    return rand();
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(foo2);
}
```

Comment: There are tons of things written about pointers. Elaborate what you mean that I don't understand about pointers.